# What’s the best way to migrate SSH keys and Certs from one Mac to another?

Tags: macos

I’m curious what some of you guys do to migrate your systems from an old Mac to a new one.

I’m in the process of a migration right now, and I usually just do a clean install and copy files over. This time, however, I have developer certificates from the App Store, and additional SSH keys that I can’t afford to lose.

My issue is that my old Mac was messed up from a power failure, so there’s something wonky in the OS and I don’t want to copy system files using Migration Assistant.

What would be the best way to move SSH keys and certificates from one Mac to another?

Comment: What form are the SSH keys stored in (i.e. are they in ~/.ssh, or in your keychain, or somewhere else)? Also, do you have them backed up? If you "can’t afford to lose" them, you *need* a backup. When backing up certs, always make certain you back up the private key along with the cert itself, because without the private key a cert is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Migration Assistant does NOT copy system files if you don't want it to.

Use Migration Assistant. When it asks what you want to migrate, just select your user account. Don't select the other categories of computer and network settings if you think those settings are untrustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating from a MacBook to a new MacBook (with M1) the migration assistant pulls over the terminal, and the passcode and keys just work on the new computer. You can proceed to work from the new computer as you did before.

You will need to make sure you are able to verify that you erased all from your old computer. They are kept in hidden files.